# VFP - Copy a free table between projects

Tags: visual-foxpro

A project **test1.pjx** has a free table in it (Project manager | Data | Free tables). I would like to copy that table structure and all its data (ten records) into another project **Test2.pjx**.

How can I do that, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's a free table and the projects are in separate folders, simply use the regular copy function in windows explorer to copy it to the second project's folder.  Then start up VFP and go to data, and add the table to the project and that should do it.

Comment: Anytime Andrew, if you don't mind would you please "accept" my answer, helps us in the community.

Comment: Thanks again Hank.  I must learn the correct behaviour!  Is this the UpArrow and DownArrow on the left of your answer?  I have experimented with this, and changed it to '3', then to '1' and then back to '2' again - finally back to '3'.  Is that correct?  Or is there an 'Accept' button which I should click.  Your answer was very helpful!

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I noticed my reputation went up, the official way to accept an answer is "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in."  good luck in the future